# Can someone please tell me what this means?

Tags: brainfuck

Do the following sets of characters have a meaning? Thank you

```
+++++++++[ >+++++++++<]>+ ++.<++++[ >++++<]>++++.+.<+++[ ->+++<]>+.<+++[ >---<]>. <+++[ >+++<]>+.
```

Comment: You should share the complete scenario, when you are getting this message.

Comment: What message???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closer a little bit your BrainFck code, you will notice that doing:

```
+++++ ++++[ >+++ +++++ +<]
```

located at your first loop, is the same as:

```
+[><]
```

or:

```
+[]
```

or even:

```
-[><]
```

Only a little more confusing..

Comment: I don't remember my Brainf*ck, but do the bytes wrap-around to zero when their values go above the maximum (Either 255 or 127)?
If that's the case, the loop may terminate.

Comment: I see, Its a message I go from someone and Im trying to decipher it, I appreciate you all who are looking into this

Answer (score 2):

This is not C++ or python.
This is Brainf*ck.

The first loop looks suspect though :)

Comment: not only the first loop :/ looks like only one of these five loops has a break condition